# Exchange 2010 EWS Delete Message

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

How do I delete email messages in a mailbox using EWS?

There doesn't seem to be much online for it?

I'm planning an application and I need to know if it's possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Item class has a Delete method. You can open the message and then delete it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.delete.aspx

Comment: Excellent thank you.  I'm still waiting for my Exchange 2010 to be configured for me to develop against but this is key to my application.  Thanks for the reply.